# Algorithm caption should be on top and and flushed left

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions

I want the caption of my algorithm to be on top and flushed left:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Sketch of our Compression Algorithm}
\label{fig:GENIDEA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While{Input contains characters}
\State Find matching reference block $B$ for current input position
\State Perform referential compression with respect to $B$ until we cannot find ``long'' matches anymore
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"on top" can be realized using `\restylefloat` offered by the `float` package which is used by the `algorithm` package. (Unfortunately the `algorithm` package does not offer an package option `plaintop` for that.)

"flushed left" can be realized using `\captionsetup[algorithm]{...}` offered by the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

% Change float style of algorithm from "ruled" to "plaintop"
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{algorithm}

% Make algorithm captions left-aligned
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Sketch of our Compression Algorithm}
\label{fig:GENIDEA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While{Input contains characters}
\State Find matching reference block $B$ for current input position
\State Perform referential compression with respect to $B$ until we cannot find ``long'' matches anymore
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Figure caption is affected. Is there another way?

Comment: @jeecabz In what way the figure caption is affected? (This should not happen and is not happening at my PC if I extend my example code with a figure.)

Comment: My apology. I miss some of the data when copying your code.. thanks

Comment: @jeecabz I'm glad it works now for you, too. But why have you deleted your own answer? (If you have the possibility to undelete it please do so.) Using `floatrow` instead of `float` is a valid and mentionable alternative since the `algorithm` package work with both of them.

Comment: my answer is now undeleted.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer of my own question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[plain]{algorithm}
\floatsetup[algorithm]{capposition=top}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[algorithm]{singlelinecheck=off}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Sketch of our Compression Algorithm}
\label{fig:GENIDEA}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\While{Input contains characters}
  \State Find matching reference block $B$ for current input position
  \State Perform referential compression with respect to $B$ until we cannot find    ``long'' matches anymore
\EndWhile
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```